# Is it common to have many loop cuts?

Tags: mesh, workflow, topology

I am building a house, and I mainly work with loopcuts.
I do not delete any faces because that breaks future loop cuts (they would stop where I have deleted a face).
Now my model looks really wild, and I will have to delete many faces when I am done.
I would like to ask if my approach is common and if this happens to anybody or if I am doing something weird here.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Continuing many of those loops seems unnecessary.  It looks like you have loops that are only used to define the window covers but the loops continue across the rest of the model.  If those flaps,doors and windows were separate pieces then you would not have to do that.  It's going to be difficult to make changes to that model later if you decide to do so.

Comment: You can also use the knife tool to add a small loop cut in a particular place, for example to add a window, really handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to add loop cuts to a model. It is also common to keep loop cuts to a minimum.

A bit of planning can help prevent loop cuts getting too excessive. In your example you have loop cuts to define edges of parts of your window shutters, these don't need to continue all the way around the house. The window shutter could be an object that is separate from the house with loops cuts that only exist in the shutter. Even if you keep everything contained in one mesh, you can have disconnected mesh parts that contain loop cuts that are local to each part.